# FsUnit `should equal` fails on `Some []`

Tags: f#, nunit, fsunit

When I run this FsUnit test with NUnit 2.6.3,

```
let f xs = Some (List.map ((+) 2) xs)

[<Test>]
let test() =
  f []
  |> should equal (Some [])
```

I get:

```
Result Message: 
Expected: <Some([])>
  But was:  <Some([])>
Result StackTrace:  
at FsUnit.TopLevelOperators.should[a,a](FSharpFunc`2 f, a x, Object y)
```

The test fails even though the Expected and Actual in the message are the same. What happened?

Comment: This looks like FsUnit has modified the semantics of `=` - running equivalent code but using `=` instead of `should equal` returns what you would expect.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667372/what-unit-testing-frameworks-are-available-for-f/5669263#5669263 - Unquote always does what I mean and much more besides

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that FsUnit uses untyped mechanism under the hood so `Expected` is inferred as `object` by the type checker (see the `Object y` part in the stacktrace).

A workaround is to add type annotation for generic values i.e.

```
[<Test>]
let test() =
  f []
  |> should equal (Some ([]: int list))
```

Several people have been bitten by this e.g. [Weird None behaviour in type providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515938/weird-none-behaviour-in-type-providers).

Beauty of fluent assertions is pointless to me once they're no longer type-safe. I suggest to create a [type-safe alternative](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/blob/master/tests/service/FsUnit.fs#L19):

```
let shouldEqual (x: 'a) (y: 'a) = 
    Assert.AreEqual(x, y, sprintf "Expected: %A\nActual: %A" x y)
```

Comment: This is available in `FsUnitTyped`: https://fsprojects.github.io/FsUnit/FsUnitTyped.html

Answer (score 4):

This is because your two empty lists are of different types. See the types of `actual` and `expected` in this version of your test:

```
[<Test>]
let test() =
  let expected = Some []
  let actual = f []
  actual |> should equal expected
```

`expected` is `'a list option` and actual is `int list option`, so they are not equal.

If you give the compiler some hints about the expected result then it will work.

```
[<Test>]
let test() =
  f []
  |> should equal (Some List.empty<int>)
```