# F# and NUnit: Structured output of record types on test failure

Tags: unit-testing, f#, nunit, fsunit, f#-unquote

I'm using NUnit to unit test F# code using Resharper's test runner inside Visual Studio 2013. I have several F# record and discriminated union types in the projects and functions that return instances of these types, such as:

```
type MyRecord = { A : int; B : int }
let f () = { A = 4; B = 7 }
```

Now when I write a test case (using FSUnit) like the following:

```
[<Test>] let ``test that always fails`` () = f () |> should be { A = 77; B = 99 }
```

I get a very non-helpful output message along the lines of "Expected: MyNamespace.MyRecord but found: MyNamespace.MyRecord".

The problem is of course that NUnit apparently uses `object.ToString()` to generate the output message, whereas I'd like it to use `sprintf "%A" object` instead to generate a more helpful output message like "Expected: { A = 77; B = 99} but found: { A = 4; B = 7}".

I know that I could overwrite `ToString` for all record and discriminated union types like this:

```
type MyRecord = { A : int; B : int } with override this.ToString () = sprintf "%A" this
```

However, this clutters up the type definition with code that is solely required for testing purposes and somewhat violates the don't-repeat-yourself principle when copy&pasting this code to all type definitions. Note also that adding overriding members in a type augmentation is deprecated in F# 3.1.

**Old question**

So, the question is: Is there a way to get structured output for failing NUnit tests without explicitly overriding `ToString`? Is there some plugin mechanism for NUnit? I've checked NUnit's sources, there doesn't seem to be an obvious or supported way of doing that. The solution doesn't have to be fast - after all, the code would only execute in failing unit tests. It should, however, be general and work for all F# record and discriminated union types added in the future, without requiring any code changes. Thanks.

**New question**

As Mark Seemann pointed out in the comments, the Unquote library is an alternative that doesn't have the problem with unstructured output. So I'll replace FSUnit with Unquote. However, there is one other problem with Unquote: It uses F#'s reflection library to evaluate and reduce discriminated unions. Apparently, reflection can't deal with internal types defined in another library, causing all unit tests to fail with an exception. The workaround is to make all types public, which is not ideal, obviously.

So my setup is: A library that contains the internal types that should be tested; that library uses the `InternalsVisibileTo` attribute to make its internals visible to the testing assembly. When tests are executed, Unquote uses F#'s reflection which in turn seems to be unable to correctly reflect the internal types.

Is there another known workaround?

Comment: I don't know if you can solve the problem with that particular stack, but I'd like to recommend [Unquote](https://code.google.com/p/unquote) instead of FSUnit. With Unquote, you'll not have that problem.

Comment: Thanks. While I do like the idea behind Unquote, unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem: When I use the `=?` operator, I also get the unstructured ToString() output, when I use `test <@ ... @>` I get an exception somewhere deep within the Unquote library. It does work fine for simple test cases, however.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but here's what I do: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/03/21/composed-assertions-with-unquote

Comment: OK, so I figure out what the problem was: Unquote doesn't work with internal types defined in another assembly (that allows the test assembly to access its internals via the InternalsVisibleTo attribute). Ok, so now I either have a redundant `ToString` overload or all of my types must be public. Any ideas? Edit: Also, this doesn't seem to be an Unquote problem but rather a problem with F#'s reflection for discriminated unions.

Comment: Yes: don't test internal types via InternalsVisibleTo. Unit tests should never be expressed via non-public APIs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1093481/126014

Comment: While I generally agree with you, in this particular case that would make unit testing impossible and allow integration tests only. We're writing a compiler, therefore the only public API is "compile these files" and then you get the generated output. We obviously want to test the internal types at the various stages of the compiler. Plus the fact that it might not be good practice doesn't mean that someone might not have found a workaround for this bug in the F# libraries.

Comment: Hi @AxelHabermaier - I am the author of Unquote and plan on researching the scenario you describe when I get a chance (hopefully in the next day or two). In the meantime, my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22486115/236255 regarding testing non-public methods in F# with Unquote may help as a workaround.

Comment: @AxelHabermaier That you have an overall goal doesn't mean that you can't break it down into (public) steps. That's what TDD is all about. For compilers, these steps are well-known, and include building Parse Trees and Abstract Syntax Trees...

Comment: @AxelHabermaier I was not able to reproduce the issue you described. I had no problem evaluating / testing internal classes, methods, modules, and functions with Unquote... if this is still a problem for you, please feel free to open an issue at https://code.google.com/p/unquote/issues/list with a reproducing VS Solution linked or attached.

Answer (score 4):

You can override messages provided by NUnit:

```
let shouldEqual (x: 'T) (y: 'T) = 
    Assert.AreEqual(x, y, sprintf "Expected: %A\nActual: %A" x y)
```

It will work well as far as `sprintf "%A"` goes in F#.

There is one more reason to prefer this version to `should equal`. This is type-safe and doesn't cause mysterious failing tests on generic values (see [FsUnit `should equal` fails on `Some []`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989847/fsunit-should-equal-fails-on-some/23991168#23991168) and [Weird None behaviour in type providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515938/weird-none-behaviour-in-type-providers))